# fastlane wasn't found on your system. did you run 'sudo gem install fastlane'?

Tags: fastlane

When I try to run the command from my project it failed. But the fastlane command get the session. If I try to run app it shows the error as

```
2021-07-27  fastlane wasn't found on your system. did you run 'sudo gem install fastlane'?
2021-07-27 [FATAL] trying to use produce but fastlane wasn't located. see error above as well.
```

My machine has

```
 % fastlane -v
fastlane installation at path:
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.188.0/bin/fastlane
-----------------------------
[✔]  
fastlane 2.188.0
 % which fastlane
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/fastlane
```

Comment: Try launching the command with your user not root (with sudo) in your project

Comment: Not worked with sudo

Comment: Are you following this page: https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/ or something else?

Comment: I have installed rvm version and then installed fastlane using the gem install fastlane.

Comment: Post rvm setup, have you used this `sudo gem install fastlane -NV` or something else?

Comment: I have used gem install fastlane and also tried with sudo gem install fastlane.

Comment: Note: I can able to run the fastlane session command successfully. But while ruuning the app it shows the above error. How does it possible? rvm install 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the above by installing the fastlane in the /usr/local/bin folder

sudo gem install -i /usr/local/bin fastlane